# apache thrift C++ server timeout client connections

Tags: c++, thrift

I am using apache thrift 0.9.3 in C++ with a TThreadPoolServer with a 15 thread limit.

I am running into a problem whereby a remote client may connect to my server, and so use up a thread, but then never disconnect. That connection thread on the server then remains "in use" forever. If this happens 15 times, my server blocks up.

Is there any way to tell the server to disconnect a client after a set time? This seems to be such an obvious problem, I feel there must be a solution which I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and asking around, it seems that the way to do it is to call setKeepAlive(true) on the TServerSocket passed to the TServerTransport.

Certainly after doing this I do see the thread pool count drop again around 30mins after killing the clients. I can't seem to find a way to change the timeout length though (setRecvTimeout() / setSendTimeout() don't change this).